How to check if a specific list element is a number?
I have 2 lists, one that contains both numbers and strings and one only numbers:
list1 = [1, 2, 'A', 'B', 3, '4']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

My goal is to print from list2 only the numbers that have another number (both as number or string) in the same index in list1.
Expected output:
[1,2,5,6]

I have tried the following code:
lenght1 = len(list1)

for i in range(lenght1):
    if (list1[i].isdigit()): 
        print(list2[i])

But I receive the following error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Same error with .isnumber().
Is there a way to check a specific list element if it is a number?

You define "number" here as either an actual int, or a numeric string. Both of those will need different tests. E.g. isinstance(list1[i], int) or ...…

That checks it it's a string that looks like a number; as above if you want to check it's an actual number value you need to check the type of the value first.

What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?

It's worth asking yourself why your list can contain both numbers and strings in the first place.

This could be solved in a one-liner solution, like so:
list1 = [1,2,'A','B',3,'4']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print([list2[index] for index, x in enumerate(list1) if isinstance(x, int)])

But we can't check if a string can become an int in this specific case. Basically, using list comprehension, we filter the first list and we create a new list based on the second one, so we should implement a way to check if a string can become an int.
To do so, we need one more check (and we'll move to a foreach for better readability).
list1 = [1,2,'A','B',3,'4']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
output_list = []
for index, x in enumerate(list1):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        output_list.append(list2[index])
    if isinstance(x, str):
        if x.isdigit():
            output_list.append(list2[index])

In conclusion, isdigit() is only available for strings, that's why you get the error. You loop through integers too, so it doesn't exist.
Note that this code is NOT flexible and it only covers the specific case. For example, if negative numbers are prompted or lists are of different lengths, it will break.
If we want to also cover the negative numbers case, a quick fix is to swap from x.isdigit() to a try-except, like so:
list1 = [1,2,'A','B',3,'4']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
output_list = []
for index, x in enumerate(list1):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        output_list.append(list2[index])
    if isinstance(x, str):
        try:
            int(x)
            output_list.append(list2[index])
        except:
            continue

If it can't be converted to int, then go to the next iteration.

By the way, no need to enumerate, zip is your friend: [num2 for num1, num2 in zip(list1, list2) if isinstance(num1, int)]

Your first code fragement does not produce the required output. OP states that list1 may contain "numbers". So, presumably, an element value of "-4" would be acceptable. Your code would not give the correct output in such a case

I agree, @SIGHUP. But the second one does. I totally understand that this code doesn't cover all the cases (it will break if lists are of different sizes), BUT it gives the correct output. The first fragment is to explain how it works. There truly is room for improvement, but if it solved the problem, then that's what matters. I added a disclaimer and improved the answer overall.

Make them strings?
list1 = [1,2,'A','B',3,'4']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if str(x).isdigit():
        print(y)

Attempt This Online!

Might be a problem if floats are also considered acceptable, but a very elegant solution

@Tomerikoo Yeah, I took OP's usage of isdigit as indication that they don't have floats or worse.

Does't work for negative integers, either.

There are many ways to do this. One is to call float() for each of the elements in list1. If the element successfully converts to float (i.e., it's a "number" in some form) then choose the corresponding element from list2
Like this:
list1 = [1, 2, "A", "B", 3, "4"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

r = []

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    try:
        float(a)
        r.append(b)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(r)

Output:
[1, 2, 5, 6]

